# Handling response of javascript injection wkWebKit

Tags: swift, safari

Im following this example to retrieve a DOM element in swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-run-javascript-on-a-wkwebview-with-evaluatejavascript

```
wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(result)
    } else {
        print(error ?? "Error")
    }
}
```

But im getting this error:

```
 nil
 Error
 App(28447,0x137b3bc40) malloc: *** error for object 0x170b9140: 
 pointer being freed was not allocated
 *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

If I just do a console log and inspect in safari it works fine:

```
wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("console.log('Hello World!')")
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is nil. You actually got results.

Either change "!=" to "=="

or change the whole line:

```
if error != nil {
```

to

```
if result != nil {
```